# Stuck my modal wont open instead lists the info on my page

Tags: html, css, popup, modal-dialog

Having issues with my model window. I want it to open the modal to show a larger version of the photo and description when click the thumbnail. I cant get it to work right the only time ive been able to get it to pop up the info it also doubled my thumbnail image. right now it instead of popping up it just puts the info on the original page.

```css
.modalWindow {
position: fixed;
font-family: arial;
font-size:80%;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
z-index: 99999;
opacity:0;
-webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
-moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
pointer-events: none;
}
.modalHeader h2 { color: #189CDA; border-bottom: 2px groove #efefef; }
.modalWindow:target {
opacity:1;
pointer-events: auto;
}
.modalWindow > div {
width: 500px;
position: relative;
margin: 10% auto;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
background: #fff;
}
.modalWindow .modalHeader { padding: 5px 20px 0px 20px; }
.modalWindow .modalContent { padding: 0px 20px 5px 20px; }
.modalWindow .modalFooter { padding: 8px 20px 8px 20px; }
.modalFooter {
background: #F1F1F1;
border-top: 1px solid #999;
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 13px 12px -14px #888;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 13px 12px -14px #888;
box-shadow: inset 0px 13px 12px -14px #888;
}
.modalFooter p {
color:#D4482D;
text-align:right;
margin:0;
padding: 5px;
}
.ok{
background: #606061;
color: #FFFFFF;
line-height: 25px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
-webkit-border-radius: 2px;
-moz-border-radius: 2px;
border-radius: 2px;
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}
.ok {
position: absolute;
right: 5px;
top: 5px;
width: 22px;
height: 22px;
font-size: 10px;
}
.ok, {
width:80px;
float:right;
margin-left:20px;
}
.ok:hover { background: #189CDA; }
.ok { float:none; clear: both; }
```

```html
<a href="#openmodal"> <img src="http://www.papercraftsquare.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/RX-0-Unicorn-Gundam-V5-Papercraft.jpg" width="200px" height="200px" alt="Banshee"></a>
<figure>
        <h4>RX-0 Unicorn 02
        Banshee Norn</h4>
      </figure>
      <form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="YZER6V8UMEATA">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
<div id="openModal" class="modalWindow">
    <div>
      <div class="modalHeader">
                 <h2>Gundam Unicorn</h2>
                 <a href="#ok" title="ok" class="ok">X</a>
             </div>

             <div class="modalContent">
               <img src="http://www.papercraftsquare.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/RX-0-Unicorn-Gundam-V5-Papercraft.jpg" width="400px" height="400px" align:left;>
                 <p>Line1</p>
                 <p>Line 2</p>
             </div>

             <div class="modalFooter">
                 <a href="#ok" title="ok" class="ok">OK</a>

             </div>

      </a>
```

Comment: First of all **#IDs** must be unique, you will need to change that before anything. Furthermore, the second before last rule has `ok, {...}` so it will be ignored. Finally, SIMPLIFY, keep things simple by stripping redundant code and combine rules. And add `* { outline: 1px dashed }` to your code so you can see what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.modalWindow {
position: fixed;
font-family: arial;
font-size:80%;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
z-index: 99999;
opacity:0;
-webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
-moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
pointer-events: none;
}
.modalHeader h2 { color: #189CDA; border-bottom: 2px groove #efefef; }
.modalWindow:target {
opacity:1;
pointer-events: auto;
}
.modalWindow > div {
width: 500px;
position: relative;
margin: 10% auto;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
background: #fff;
}
.modalWindow .modalHeader { padding: 5px 20px 0px 20px; }
.modalWindow .modalContent { padding: 0px 20px 5px 20px; }
.modalWindow .modalFooter { padding: 8px 20px 8px 20px; }
.modalFooter {
background: #F1F1F1;
border-top: 1px solid #999;
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 13px 12px -14px #888;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 13px 12px -14px #888;
box-shadow: inset 0px 13px 12px -14px #888;
}
.modalFooter p {
color:#D4482D;
text-align:right;
margin:0;
padding: 5px;
}
.ok{
background: #606061;
color: #FFFFFF;
line-height: 25px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
font-weight: bold;
-webkit-border-radius: 2px;
-moz-border-radius: 2px;
border-radius: 2px;
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
}
.ok {
position: absolute;
right: 5px;
top: 5px;
width: 22px;
height: 22px;
font-size: 10px;
}
.ok {
width:80px;
float:right;
margin-left:20px;
}
.ok:hover { background: #189CDA; }
.ok { float:none; clear: both; }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<a href="#openmodal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#openModal"> <img src="http://www.papercraftsquare.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/RX-0-Unicorn-Gundam-V5-Papercraft.jpg" width="200px" height="200px" alt="Banshee"></a>
<figure>
        <h4>RX-0 Unicorn 02
        Banshee Norn</h4>
      </figure>
      <form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="YZER6V8UMEATA">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>


      </a>
      
      <div id="openModal" class="modalWindow modal fade">
    <div>
      <div class="modalHeader">
                 <h2>Gundam Unicorn</h2>
                 <a href="#ok" title="ok" class="ok" data-dismiss="modalWindow">X</a>
             </div>

             <div class="modalContent">
               <img src="http://www.papercraftsquare.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/RX-0-Unicorn-Gundam-V5-Papercraft.jpg" width="400px" height="400px" align:left;>
                 <p>Line1</p>
                 <p>Line 2</p>
             </div>

             <div class="modalFooter">
                 <a href="#ok" title="ok" class="ok">OK</a>

             </div>
             </div>
             </div>
```

Comment: You really need to read [answer], simply posting some code is not good enough. We are not a bunch of code correcter volunteers. Make people learn. Even if you are being nice.